# Will i lose my facebook acount if I force- stop it?

Tags: notifications

My facebook account is causing my mobile phone to run slow and it keeps restarting. Is it safe to force stop facebook?

Comment: Adding to what Lucky said - you will not lose the Facebook account even if you uninstall the app.

Comment: No. It wont be deleted. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not your account that is slowing down your smart phone, it's the app itself (don't worry, even I had the same problem).

Your phone is probably weak or you are running too much of apps and processes at the same time, saving less resources for *facebook*.

So, to answer your qustion: **No, your account will not be deleted if you force stop facebook (or any other app like *google+*).** Deleting an account is a totaly different process. For that you will have to request facebook to delete your account. But what's hapening in your case is simply stopping the app (for geeks: the front end part) from doing further work. Your account detailes and stuff are perfectly safe at facebook's server (for geeks: back end).

So go ahead, force stop your app. You can still use facebook from their mobile site, which is not heavy and much resource consuming.

Happy facebooking =)